# retrieve data from gridview row to an asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I would like to retrieve a row from the gridview by clicking on ImageButton (Booking):
here is the code of my grid view:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="284px" 
                         CssClass="tb" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

                         <Columns>
                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" Booking">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:ImageButton ID="booking" runat="server"   HeaderText="Booking" ImageUrl="booking_icon.ico" PostBackUrl="form.aspx"/>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Trade" HeaderText="Trade" SortExpression="Trade" />
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="CARRIER" HeaderText="CARRIER" 
                                 SortExpression="CARRIER" />
                            </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

The textbox of the form.aspx page that should be filed from the gridview row:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="trade" runat="server" CssClass="input , focus"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="carrier" runat="server" CssClass="input , focus"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add GridView RowCommand event and command argument for image button where you can pass an id or something to determine the current row.

```
  <asp:GridView  onrowcommand="gvRowCommand" ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="284px" 
                     CssClass="tb" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SomeId") %>' ID="booking" runat="server"   HeaderText="Booking" ImageUrl="booking_icon.ico" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

C#

```
   protected void gvRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
      var someId = e.CommandArgument;
   }
```

VB.Net

```
 Protected Sub gvRowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gv.RowCommand

   Dim someId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

End Sub
```

You can refer msdn for more : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Comment: Var Trade= e.CommandArgument is returning an error!! Can we use var in Vb.net ??  I want to retrieve this row value in textbox in my form.aspx page, how I can do this !?

Comment: There no more error now, should I add something to my textBox code the textbow has "trade" as id ??

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to get a value of the row selected with the ImageButton in mygridview, the value here is "Trade", i want to get this value in other page (Form.aspx) exactly in the textBox field of this form, the textbox filed has like id="trade" as shown on the post question

Comment: Yes, you can bind the selected commandargument to the textbox directly trade.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

Comment: Actually the textbox is in another page, (form.aspx)! That's why it returns an error in CommandArgument !

Comment: If gridview is in one page and you are trying to display gridview selected data in to Form.aspx page, If yes, you may need to redirect to form.aspx page and pass data via querystring and in destination page you have to pull the querystring value and display it. 
Response.Redirect("form.aspx?param="+e.CommandArgument.ToString())
Form.aspx - trade.Text = Request.QueryString["param"]

Comment: It's working now Thank you so much!

Just for the (Request.QueryString["param"]) can do this with request.form ??

Comment: no, if you are passing through querystring, you have to get it using Request.QueryString or just Request[""]. For form post you can use Request.Form. Note : Request[] can get querystring and form post values.

Comment: okk! And if I want to retrieve more than one value from the row of the gridView, what should I change ?

Comment: Add multiple parameters like Response.Redirect("form.aspx?param=1&param=2&param=3", false)

Comment: sorry to bother you! In my case I have no id (primary key) in the table that the gridview uses!So is there any way to do more that one Eval in the command argument ?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple values in CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Param1") + "|" +Eval("Param2")%>'. Note: You need to split in codebehind

Comment: Dim parameters As String() = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument).Split(New Char() {"|"c})