# how to make a loop until an event in visual studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

**how to make a loop until an event in visual studio ?**

I want to get value of a Label from a DataGrid cell, until user clicks on button1.
can someone help me with the code ?

LOGIC:

```
Do
..
... 
textbox1.text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.tostring
Until button1.click
```

Comment: Please tag the question correctly. My suggestion is to tag the language too like c# or VB.Net.

Comment: ok thanks (sorry i am new)

Comment: **Windows** more or less does that for you.  When they click a button you will get an event, no need to give the app and computer something to do until then.

Comment: Thanks , i found the event ^^

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to loop it at the first place? Label value once set doesn't change. If you want the label value to be empty you can try setting it to empty once the button1.click event triggers.

Comment: that's just an exemple for what i want to do , well i want that a textbox get DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value when user click on the button (sorry for my bad english )

Comment: iam working on a project connected to a database , i have a button (Modify) , i want when i change values in the data grid and when i press modif the database values changes too , the problem is : i want that an object get the value of the first cell(id) in the row before the user change it ,  so i can call the previous id in the sql command

Comment: Where is that button placed on your page, is it inside the datagrid or outside of that?

Comment: @Stand Still, ask questions in comment section instead of using Answer section.

Comment: There are many ways of doing it. One of them would be to Use a RowCommand Event in your GridView control. You Can read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311213/retrieve-data-from-gridview-row-to-an-asp-net-form

Comment: @SuvenduShekharGiri, Sorry about that, I am new to this forum. Will Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private ButtomClicked As Boolean

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ButtomClicked = True
End Sub

Sub WaitClick()
    Do Until ButtomClicked
        Application.DoEvents() 'TO prevent form freezing
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(200) 'Optional
        TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
    Loop
End Sub
```